# Private Venues for javascript here api

Tags: javascript, api, here-api

Is there a way to access private venues from here JavaScript API?

I want to load map with private venue using here JavaScript API. I found Android and iOS SDK for private venues but for JavaScript there are no documentation for private venues.

Answer (score 0):

This use case is not supported in the version 3.0. But is is planned to support private venues in the upcoming version of the API. 
Meanwhile you could workaround with  displaying an overlay on the map like here:

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/infoBubbles/custom-tile-overlay